# Reducible families of bounded operators on non-separable Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Is it correct to say: for any family of bounded operators (proper subset of B(H)) acting on a non-separable Hilbert space there is a non-trivial subspace of the Hilbert space that reduces the family? I know that this is true for any operator on  the space so, I assume that it holds also for the von Neumann algebra generated by this operator. Can we generalize to non-commutative families?
If the answers is positive (or positive with certain restriction imposed on the family) how can we show it? Is there any reference?

Comment: Why the non-separable hypothesis? What does it mean that a subspace reduces the family? What is true for any operator? Please explain.

Comment: Reducibility: all operators in the family are reduced by the same non-trivial subspace. In non-separable H.S. all operators are reducible, while in separable ones the set of irreducible operators is dense in B(H).

Comment: Do you mean that the subspace and its orthogonal are invariant by the operator? It seems strange to me that the non-separable result is better than the separable one.  Do you have references for this?

Comment: Halmos 1968 "Irreducible operators"; Dan Voiculescu. A non-commutative Weyl-von Neumann theorem. Rev. Roumaine Math. Pures Appl. 21
(1976), no. 1, 97–113.

Comment: The family may consist of all bounded operators. Then it cannot be reducible.

Comment: Ryszard Szwarc
 you are right. I should have placed a restriction - proper subset of B(H). I will add it

Comment: @val72:  It is well-known that the Schrödinger representation of the Heisenberg group on $L^2(\Bbb{R})$ is an irreducible representation, so it has no invariant subspace.  The image of the group in $\mathcal{U}(L^2(\Bbb{R}))$ is not all $\mathcal{B}(L^2(\Bbb{R}))$.

Comment: @John Doe. Agree, but what this result has to do with nonseparable Hilbert spaces? To my knowledge L2 (R) is a separable H.S.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, but I think that even in the non-separable case, the commutant of the entire unitary group is equal to $\Bbb{C}\mathbf{1}$.

Comment: @JohnDoe Every bounded operator is a linear combination of at most four unitary operators. Hence the set of unitaries  spans $B(H).$